# Differentiate between 404 error and is loading in react and render the components base on that. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a skeleton component on loading of the data or 404 error component if data not found so far i have tried using if else statements and logical operators so far none work properly.

```
const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
const [postExternal, setPostExternal] = useState([]);

const fetchPost = () => {
  axios.get(`${API_ONE}/posts?id=${id}`).then((response) => {
    setPost(response.data);
  });
  axios.get(`${API_TWO}/posts?id=${id}`).then((response) => {
    setPostExternal(response.data);
  });
  return;
};

const location = useLocation();
const id = location.pathname.split('/')[2];

useEffect(() => {
  fetchPost();
}, [id]);

{
  post && postExternal && (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <img src={postExternal} />
    </div>
  );
}
{
  !post &&
    (post && post.id === postExternal.id ? (
      <NotFound message='not found' />
    ) : (
      <SkeletonItemPage />
    ));
}
```

Note: The data is fetched from two different apis

Comment: You have `!post && (post && ...`

Comment: Maybe ```!post || (post && ...``` ?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
  fetchPost();
}, [id, post, postExternal]); add these to your useEffect and let me know if that worked

Comment: it seems to me that you're not returning anything from your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a loading state variable as the follow:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
```

Then your fetchPosts function would be like:

```
  const fetchPost = () => {
            const apiOnePromise = axios.get(`${API_ONE}/posts?id=${id}`);
            const apiTwoPromise = axios.get(`${API_TWO}/posts?id=${id}`);
            //toggle loader
            setLoading(true);
            Promise.all([apiOnePromise, apiTwoPromise])
                .then(values => {
                    //handle your responses here
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    //toggle loader again
                    setLoading(false);
                })
        };
```

Using this loading variable you can differentiate between the statues, so with your jsx you can do:

```
   { loading && <SkeletonItemPage /> }
   { !loading && posts.length === 0 && <NotFound message='not found' />  }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch i did had a thought of using loading state but go confused on where exactly do i get the values from.

Comment: @YeshwanthB read about this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all